# What does "according to my application” means?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, british-english, non-standard-english, elizabethan-english

For example:

“The ship was masted according to the proportion of the navy; but on my application the masts were shortened, as I thought them too much for her, considering the nature of the voyage.” - William Bligh

“according to my application of it, I trust that it will prove, not merely an interesting record, but, in a considerable degree, useful and instructive.” - Thomas De Quincy

Comment: This is a non-standard usage of "application". Both of the men you've quoted lived about 200 years ago. I can't even guess at the meaning from this context.

Comment: @gotube I disagree that these usages are archaic: see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meanings are different in the two sentences: I refer to the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/application) for possible meanings.

In the first sentence the relevant meaning is "an official request for something, usually in writing". William Bligh asked in writing to have his ship's masts shortened.

For the second sentence, the relevant meaning is "a way in which something can be used for a particular purpose".

Neither meaning is archaic. The first meaning, for example, can be used in relation to an application form. Here is a typical, recent example of the second form:

> Composite structures show many applications in modern engineering - *Shell structures -Pietraszkiewicz & Witkowski, 2017*

Note that the meaning in the second sentence is the root of the IT word "app", which is an abbreviation of "application program".